# Unable to locate a dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have few fields along with text field ,date, rich text editor, dropdown and browse button to upload image. I am getting error as unable to locate element on selecting the dropdown after rich text editor. Here is my code:

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;



public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[])throws NoSuchElementException,InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("url");

        driver.findElement(By.id("area_number")).sendKeys("1221");
        driver.findElement(By.id("street_name")).sendKeys("abc");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email_of_owner")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("name_of_contact")).sendKeys("Test Papri");
        driver.findElement(By.id("contact_date")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/button[4]")).click();


        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"))));


//Code for Rich text editor goes here//

            jsExecutor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
//Active value is being displayed in a li tag as selected after a button is clicked so tried with this.

           WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
          wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]")));
```

//Select dropdown is a button so tried to click it.This is the xpath of the button

```
           WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/button"));
           //dropdown.click();

//driver.close();
```

}
    }

Comment: Can you give me the url?

Comment: Really bad idea to use such an absolute locator xpath

Comment: i have used all other locators also still same issue. i am new in selenium if you have any solution then help ---@demouser123

Comment: Sorry i can't provide you the url, its confidential----@Rajagopalan

Comment: tried with relative xpath's still unable to locate the element..

Comment: Use the name with @ symbol in the beginning of the comment otherwise the person will not notified.

Comment: ok thanks  Rajagopalan

Comment: Provide html code.

Comment: <label for="answer">Answer : </label><textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="ckeditor form-control" ></textarea>
<label for="status">Status : </label> <select name="status" id="status" >
<option value="" >select</option>
<option value="active"  selected  >active</option>
<option value="inactive"  >inactive</option>
</select>
<label for="created_at">Images : </label>
<input type="file" value="" name="images[]" id="images" class="form-control" multiple="" max="3">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect" value="Submit" />

Comment: After inserting data in ckeditor , no element is being located.

Comment: Thanks everyone, my problem is solved with  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();